# Shoreditch theme is not working when resource URL is "localhost"

Tags: shoreditch

I installed CiviCRM V5.7 with shoreditch theme on localhost computer and looks good. I am accessing a site from another computer but not looking good (UI).As per the shoreditch extension, I put 'seven' as default theme.

[image]

Comment: Have you selected the Shoreditch CSS in /civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1. ALso clearing caches?

Comment: yes. Please check image. It is working on server but when I am accessing by another client PC then it is not working.

Comment: You are using Drupal?

Comment: Yes.I am using drupal v7.59

Comment: You looked at the console on the client PC to see if anyhthng is not being loaded properly?

Comment: 2 css files showing error.  http://localhost/copy/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch-0.1-alpha30/css/bootstrap.css?r=Xx1oI (Showing server local path)

Comment: Ok so i guess you need to check your paths in your CiviCRM settings file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the URL for CSS files at "http://localhost".  This suggests that either your `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` in `civicrm.settings.php` is incorrectly set to `localhost`, or that the same problem exists in one of the directories or Resource URLs (in **Administer menu » System Settings » Directories** or **Resource URLs**).

Comment: Thanks. By default, it takes a localhost path.